# How to align with same width last six columns?

Tags: tables, columns, width

I have a table with 7 columns. The first one with long characters and other 6 that must have the same width. I wrote this code but its impossible to get the last 6 columns with the SAME columns width. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Tax-Benefit Structure\tnote{a}}
\centering
\caption{Social Expenditure}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
\hline
                                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Social Expenditure Percentage (\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GDP Percentage (\%)} \\[-0.5ex]
Type of Social Expenditure      & 2005  & 2010  & 2015  & 2005  & 2010  & 2015 \\[0.5ex]
\hline
Health                          & 17,8   & 3    & 21,9  & 1,2   & 1,9   & 2,7 \\
Promotion of Social Actions     & 1,7    & 14,1 & 20,3  & 0,1   & 1,2   & 2,5 \\
Social Welfare                  & 30,1   & 18,4 & 20,4  & 2,1   & 6     & 2,5 \\
Education                       & 8,4    & 43   & 35,8  & 3,4   & 3,7   & 4,3 \\
Science \& Technology           & 0,1    & 0,3  & 0,7   & 0     & 0     & 0,1 \\
Others                          & 0,1    & 1,8  & 0,9   & 0     & 0,2   & 0,1 \\
Total                           & 100    & 100  & 100   & 6,9   & 8,7   & 2,1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: You have seven columns and you giving 8 options in the tabular! You have to correct this first

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A full a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`(like in the answer).

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to get equal columns with such a wide header for columns 2-4; on the other hand “(\%)” already states you are using percentages, so you can omit the word.

With `siunitx` it's now easy to get equal columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Tax-Benefit Structure\tnote{a}}\label{tab:addlabel}%
\centering
\caption{Social Expenditure}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{6}{S[table-format=3.1]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Type of Social Expenditure  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Social Expenditure} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GDP} \\
                            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{(\%)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
                            & {2005} & {2010} & {2015} & {2005} & {2010} & {2015} \\
\midrule
Health                      & 17,8   &  3     & 21,9   & 1,2    & 1,9    & 2,7 \\
Promotion of Social Actions &  1,7   & 14,1   & 20,3   & 0,1    & 1,2    & 2,5 \\
Social Welfare              & 30,1   & 18,4   & 20,4   & 2,1    & 6      & 2,5 \\
Education                   &  8,4   & 43     & 35,8   & 3,4    & 3,7    & 4,3 \\
Science \& Technology       &  0,1   &  0,3   &  0,7   & 0      & 0      & 0,1 \\
Others                      &  0,1   &  1,8   &  0,9   & 0      & 0,2    & 0,1 \\
\midrule
Total                       & 100    & 100    & 100    & 6,9    & 8,7    & 2,1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Excellent. I will follow your sugestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try the next command on your preamble:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

and then use:

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{C{1.85cm}}}
```

You can change the length as you wish and of course you can use \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
%Your tabular here 
}